# Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I've been trying this the whole night

```
String querystate = " insert into provincias (Paises_idPais, Provincia, Abreviatura, Km2, Capital, `Ciudad mas grande`)"
                + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStmt;
preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(querystate);
preparedStmt.setInt(1, cID);
preparedStmt.setString(2, sName);
preparedStmt.setString(3, sAbbr);
preparedStmt.setInt(4, sArea);
preparedStmt.setString(5, sCapital);
preparedStmt.setString(6, sLargest_city);

        preparedStmt.execute();
```

When this is executed it gives me a query that looks like this:

```
insert into provincias(Paises_idPais, Provincia, Abreviatura, Km2, Capital, `Ciudad mas grande`) values (1, `a`, `a`, 1, `a`, `a`)
```

Aaaaaaand it gives me that error about field list

"Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'

This is the error i get when i used e.printStackTrace();

```
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement@202b0582:  insert into provincias (Paises_idPais, Provincia, Abreviatura, Km2, Capital, `Ciudad mas grande`) values (1, 'a', 'a', 1, 'a', 'a')

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Ciudad mas grande') values (1, 'a', 'a', 1, 'a', 'a')' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1192)
at DataAccess.DAOState.insertState(DAOState.java:38)
at Main.main(Main.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Sry for the spanish tables.

Comment: *"When this is executed it gives me a query that looks like this:"* With all due respect, I don't think it does. How are you getting that query text? JDBC will not put strings in backticks like that.

Comment: I've never seen a prepared statement put backticks in the _values_ of the insert.

Comment: Sry, i mean that when i do that while debugging, the query that it try to insert looks like that. U're right, it doesn't give me any query, it just insert without giving me nothing.

Comment: What errors do you get? Do errors normally generate exceptions? Does a query like `GIVE_ME_AN_ERROR` generate one as it should?

Comment: Check your variable values such as 'sName' that must be inserting the backticks in your query

Comment: The insert will look something like this: ``insert into provincias(Paises_idPais, Provincia, Abreviatura, Km2, Capital, `Ciudad mas grande`) values (1, 'a', 'a', 1, 'a', 'a')`` So what error/result are you getting/not getting when you run the Java code? What do you mean by "without giving me nothing"? `insert` doesn't return information to you.

Comment: @neophyte: No. If it were, the JDBC driver would escape it correctly.

Comment: It gives me an error but its just a messege i put on the "catch" during the exception.

Comment: @JuanPa: And that error has vital information in it, including the error text from MySQL. You need to examine that information, and if you still have a question, quote that information in the question.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder: Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's the error i get, since the IDE wasn't able to insert, I took that string i edited on the post and tried it by myself, but as i said, it throws that error: "Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'"

Comment: @JuanPa: That's because you used backticks where you were supposed to use `'`, and has nothing to do with your Java code. Again: **What's in the error message you get from the exception?**

Comment: As i said It gives me an error but its just a messege i put on the "catch" during the exception, and i don't know how to make it throw me a real error message and not something i write.

Comment: @JuanPa Put in a breakpoint, and inspect the exception.  There must be a specific type of exception, and there should be a message along with that.

Comment: Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64257', transport: 'socket'

That's the only thing i could get from the debugger, sry, im not being helpfull at all, i'm so new to this.

Comment: No...this means that the debugger already ended.  Add a breakpoint to a line of code by clicking on the left column next to that line (at least if you are using Eclipse or IntelliJ).

Comment: I did it now in the .execute(), where should i look for the error? It seems to be working at least on the debugger.

Comment: It isn't working, we already know this for certain.  Just step into the `catch` block and then update your question with the exception you see there.

Comment: or maybe just print the actual exception details(`e.getMessage()`) instead of printing your self-defined message?

Comment: @Baby Or maybe e.printStackTrace(), that would give all the info and where the methods are failing.

Comment: @Baby If i do that it doesn't give me any error.

Comment: @JuanPa now it makes no sense. print it, not just calling it. `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` or `System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());` as @Amnor suggested

Comment: Could be this? `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Ciudad mas grande') values (1, 'a', 'a', 1, 'a', 'a')' at line 1`.

Comment: Can you tell me where i'm using the one who doesn't not belong there?

Comment: Now that you've finally quoted the actual error in the question, we can see that the problem is the backticks on `Ciudad mas grande`. That means that either the JDBC connector you're using for MySQL has an issue with them (the usual one people use doesn't), or that your MySQL installation is configured not to use backticks as identifier quotes. (They're a non-standard MySQL thing, but as far as I know you have to actively turn them off.) Unfortunately, we can't help you, the issue is in things we can't see (your JDBC connector and MySQL configuration).

Comment: The thing was that you really helped me, it was that, the backticks, I changed them for the other one you mention and it works. Thanks for all of your patience with me. And sorry for not being able to guide you to the problem quicker. Thanks again!